# Finding the quotient group of $\mathbb{R}^{\times}/P$, where $P = \mathbb{R}^{> 0}$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group

This is Artin exercise 2.10.5.

> Identify the quotient group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}/P$, where $P$ denotes the subgroup of positive real numbers.

My attempt at solving it is as follows.

> Given $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, the left coset of $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ containing $x$ is
> $$xP = \{xk \mid k \in P\}.$$
> If $y \in xP$, then $x \sim y$, so $x^{-1} y \in P$, i.e., $\frac{1}{x} \cdot y > 0$, which is true if and only if $x,y$ have the same sign. That is, $x \sim y$ if and only if $x,y > 0$ or $x,y < 0$, so the equivalence classes are
> $$\mathbb{R}^{\times}/P = \{[+1], [-1]\}.$$
> where $[+1]$ is the positive real numbers and $[-1]$ is the negative real numbers.

Comment: Did you mean $xP=\{xk\mid k\in\color{red}P\}\,$?  $\\$  Isn't $\frac1x\cdot y>0$ also if $x,y<0$?

Comment: Oh! You are right. The first was a typo. The second one makes more sense. So what I want to say is if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, which still breaks into equivalence classes of positives and negatives. Is that right?

Comment: I believe you're correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, $\mathbb R^\times / P$ is just $\{[1],[-1]\}$ but not for the reason that you gaves: if $x>0$, then $[x] = [1]$ (since $1^{-1}x = 1x = x \in P$); and if $x<0$, then $[x] = [-1]$ (since $(-1)^{-1}x = (-1)x = -x \in P$).

Comment: I understand your explanation, but I don't understand why mine is incorrect, since I only considered a general $x$.

Comment: @JeremyS Oh, I just noticed you edited your post, but I got one question for you: so $y \in [x]$ implies that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, but, what's next? How do you conclude that $\mathbb R^\times/P = \{[1],[-1]\}$?

Comment: Well, if $y \sim x$ and $x,y$ have the same sign, then there are two cases: they're both positive or both negative. So I partitioned $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ on the basis. I did consider that I should have more rigorously proved that $\mathbb{R}^{\times}/P - \{[1], [-1]\}$ by dual containment. If $x \in R^{\times}/P$, then if it's positive, then $\frac{1}{x} \cdot y > 0$ provided $y > 0$, so $x \in [1]$; similarly, if it's negative, then $x \in [-1]$. Similarly, both $[1]$ and $[-1]$ are equivalence classes.

Comment: I edited the post with some more reasoning. Can you tell me how this looks?

Comment: Look's fine! Just a couple of comments with respect to your latter comment: $x \in \mathbb R^\times/P$ means that $x = [z]$ for some $z \in \mathbb R^\times$, so $x = [1]$ (i.e. $z \sim 1$) if $z$ is positive and $x = [-1]$ (i.e. $z \sim -1$) if $z$ is negative, that is, $x \in \mathbb R^\times/P \implies x \in \{[1],[-1]\}$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!